# What's the best tutorial for beamer, sweave and ggplot2 combined?

Tags: beamer, sweave, tutorials

I'm looking for the best example presentation publicly available on the Internet that uses beamer, sweave and ggplot2 all at the same time. Ideally it would be the actual example .Rnw file, along with associated data files, etc, rather than a user manual. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The intersection of beamer tutorials, sweave tutorials and ggplot2 tutorials might well be empty. That said, there might be some interesting stuff in their disjoint union...

Comment: I don't mean disjoint union. I mean there might be tutorials that do only two of those things. (That would be the complement of the disjoint union, minus the complement of the normal union...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Seamus, I haven't seen many good tutorials for all three ([although I found two from google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sweave+beamer+latex)), but a few few for two. (I have done all three btw, and it works well

All three

- http://famprevmed.ucsd.edu/faculty/cberry/beamer/
- [pdf](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffamprevmed.ucsd.edu%2Ffaculty%2Fcberry%2Fbeamer%2Fbeamerswv.pdf&rct=j&q=sweave%20beamer&ei=EKZlTerALYT68Aba7IHDBg&usg=AFQjCNH2S0k84UnwzCV4-6l0S_tMf-ngTA&cad=rja)

Sweave

- [pdf](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CFAQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstat.epfl.ch%2Fwebdav%2Fsite%2Fstat%2Fshared%2FRegression%2FEPFL-Sweave-powerdot.pdf&rct=j&q=sweave&ei=gKRlTZPaI4XogQe25vCYBw&usg=AFQjCNHflG1T9e6AJykZLJbk_KLs-Pm_Ag&cad=rja)
- http://www.stat.umn.edu/~charlie/Sweave/

Beamer

- http://happymutant.com/latex/misce/beamer.php
- http://www.math-linux.com/spip.php?article77

Beamer / Poster

- http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php
- http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/02/beamer-and-latex-with-keynote-theme/