# Sweave, Beamer and ggplot2

Tags: beamer, sweave, r

There's literally nothing on the internet showing how these work in conjunction with one another. I would really appreciate even the simplest example of a Rnw document that you would run with Sweave() in R.

If you could provide a title, a simple plot, centered on the page, and a page number. Please, lets see how you would do it.

TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best tutorial for beamer, sweave and ggplot2 combined?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11870/whats-the-best-tutorial-for-beamer-sweave-and-ggplot2-combined)

Comment: @Brandon: I just see that the post I linked to does not quite provide the answer to your question, but I hope it still helps.

Comment: Thank you Hendrik, but no, that post was not particularly instructive as a) those examples are outdated and do not work properly and b) they do not combine all of the required elements of my request. The reason for this question is to see a real example, however simple, of these three in action together.

Comment: I should qualify that by saying that they "do not work properly" for me. The text and images are garbled or misplaced.

Comment: @Brandon if the above linked question isn't helpful, could you try and make your question more specific?

Comment: @Seamus, I'm not sure how much more specific I could be. I'm looking for a working example of Sweave, Beamer and ggplot2 that I can use to build up from.

Comment: @Brandon so the problem is you can't even get a compilable example? Perhaps an MWE with a screenshot would help identify the problem? Don't forget to add `\listfiles` to your preamble.

Comment: @Seamus, maybe we're speaking a different language here, but @chl has already provided exactly what I was looking for. Apologies for the confusion :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example where I shamelessly copied some [R code](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7899/complex-regression-plot-in-r/7911#7911) from Cross-Validated. It can be compiled in many ways, but personally I used

```
R CMD Sweave 1.Rnw
pdflatex 1.tex
```

where `1.Rnw` actually reads:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\title{A sample Sweave demo}
\author{Author name}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\SweaveOpts{engine=R,eps=FALSE,pdf=TRUE,strip.white=all}
\SweaveOpts{prefix=TRUE,prefix.string=fig-,include=TRUE}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.6\textwidth}

\maketitle

<<echo=false>>=
set.seed(101)
library(ggplot2)
library(ellipse)
@

<<>>=
n <- 1000
x <- rnorm(n, mean=2)
y <- 1.5 + 0.4*x + rnorm(n)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)

# take a bootstrap sample
df <- df[sample(nrow(df), nrow(df), rep=TRUE),]

xc <- with(df, xyTable(x, y))
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(x=xc$x, y=xc$y, n=xc$number)
df.ell <- as.data.frame(with(df, ellipse(cor(x, y), 
                                         scale=c(sd(x),sd(y)), 
                                         centre=c(mean(x),mean(y)))))
p1 <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=n), alpha=.6) + 
  stat_smooth(data=df, method="loess", se=FALSE, color="green") + 
  stat_smooth(data=df, method="lm") +
  geom_path(data=df.ell, colour="green", size=1.2)
@

\begin{figure}
  \centering
<<fig=true,echo=false>>=
print(p1)
@
\caption{Here goes the caption.}
\label{fig:p1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

With Beamer, you just have to replace the first line with

```
\documentclass[t,ucs,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
```

or add whatever customizations you want, replace `\maketitle` with something like `\frame{\titlepage}`, and then enclose every code chunks with a `\begin{frame}[fragile] ... \end{frame}` statement. Compilation goes the same way as aforementioned.

Code chunks can be customized using, e.g.

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim}
{formatcom = {\color{Sinput}},fontsize=\scriptsize} 
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}
{formatcom = {\color{Soutput}},fontsize=\footnotesize}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}
{formatcom = {\color{Scode}},fontsize=\small}
```

It requires `fancyvrb` and needs to be somewhere after the `\begin{document}`. Personally, I hold in an external configuration file, among other stuff,

```
\definecolor{Sinput}{rgb}{0.75,0.19,0.19}
\definecolor{Soutput}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{Scode}{rgb}{0.75,0.19,0.19}
```

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Comment: When I run this, the R code that's on page three crosses the right edge of the page. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: @Brandon Cannot reproduce it: the Sweave article is 2 pages long, the Beamer slides are 3 pages long. If you mean slide #2 in the above snapshot, where actually the R code is echoed, then I guess you'll have to reduce font size -- as shown near the end of my response (I often alternate between `\footnotesize` and `\scriptsize` for S chunks). I have other templates for Beamer + Sweave that I can share on github if you like.

Comment: @chl, yes, that would be very helpful (re: templates). I'll try changing the font size. Still getting my head around this tex stuff.

Comment: @Brandon Ok, I'll do my best to gist them tomorrow.

Comment: For customizing the code chunks, could you specify where in the 1.Rnw file they would go? As well as the colouring definitions? \DefineVerbatimEnvironment ... and \definecolor where do you put these? They seem to break the output when I place them in the 1.Rnw file.

Comment: @Brandon The `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment ...` must go after your `\begin{document}`, and color definition can be put as is in your preamble. And don't forget to add `\usepackage{fancyvrb}` in the preamble. Sorry, should go to sleep now :-)

Comment: @Brandon It is even simpler to give you the [complete code](https://gist.github.com/882297) :-)

Comment: Much better, everything worked when I ran it on my end. Thanks for the example, much appreciated.